# In R what is the equivalent of @ function handle in Matlab?

Tags: r

In Matlab if I have a function f such as the signature is f(a,b,c), I can make a function which has only one variable b, which would call f with a fixed a=a1 and c=c1:

```
g = @(b) f(a1, b, c1);
```

Is there an equivalent in R, or do I just need to redefine a new function ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is also the convenient `functional::Curry` functional:

```
f <- function(a, b, c) {a + b + c}
f(1, 2, 3)
# [1] 6

library(functional)
g <- Curry(f, a = a1, c = c1)
g(b=2)
# [1] 6
g(2)
# [1] 6
```

I think an important difference with @NPE's solution is that the definition of `g` using `Curry` does not mention `b`. So you might prefer this approach when the number of arguments in `f` becomes large.

Comment: There's also `pryr::partial` and in `ptools`, `%<<%`, `%>>%` and `%()%`. It's not clear how partial evaluation and lazy evaluation of arguments should interact, and each package takes a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 5):

```
g <- function(b) f(a1, b, c1)
```