# Handle function in R?

Tags: r, matlab

I see matlab have handle function for quick compute some thing with @ symbol for call it.

So In R, do we have the same handle function?

If yes, please show me how use it.

Comment: can you explain what you want to do for those of us who do not use matlab

Comment: possible duplicate of [In R what is the equivalent of @ function handle in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636454/in-r-what-is-the-equivalent-of-function-handle-in-matlab)

Comment: I want to plug in a function as a parameter in a different function